# What are these rectangle areas and how do I remove them

Tags: modeling

I'm still a massive noob at blender and I have somehow gotten these large rectangles that are made of black dotted lines to appear all over my blend. What are they and how do I get rid of them?

[image: Rectangles]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled the display of Texture spaces for some of the objects in the scene.

You can disable it for each object separately by un-checking *Texture space* under *Display* from the *Object* panel in the *Properties* window.

[image]